# Applet image missing

Tags: java, html, image, applet, imageicon

Hello again Stackoverflow members,

The CatchTheCreature Applet class is supposed to display an image being repainted in different locations by a time delay, but for some reason the image is not being displayed.

```
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
  import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
  import java.util.Random;

  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JApplet;
  import javax.swing.Timer;

  public class CatchTheCreature extends JApplet {

private int height = 300;
private int width = 600;
private final int delay = 1001;

private ImageIcon image;
private Timer timer;
private int x, y;
private int counter = 0;
Random gn = new Random();

public void init() {
    DotListener dot = new DotListener();
    addMouseListener(dot);

    image = new ImageIcon("Monster.png");

    timer = new Timer(delay, new timerListener());
    x = 40;
    y = 40;
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

}

// Action Listener Methods
private class timerListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        x = gn.nextInt(width);
        y = gn.nextInt(height);

        repaint();
    }

}

private class DotListener implements MouseListener {

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getX() > (x) && event.getX() < (x + 60)
                && event.getY() < (y + 60) && event.getY() > (y)) {
            x = gn.nextInt(width);
            y = gn.nextInt(height);
            counter = counter + 1;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {

    }

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    image.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
    g.drawString("Clicked accuratly: " + counter, 5, 15);
}

public void start() {
    timer.start();

}

public void stop() {
    timer.stop();
}
```

}

This is my html file

```
     <applet code = CatchTheCreature width = 250 height = 300>

     </applet>
```

If someone can tell me how i can display the image icon on the applet I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ..image = new ImageIcon("Monster.png");

- The `String` based constructor to `ImageIcon` presumes the `String` to represent a `File`.
- A sand-boxed applet cannot access `File` objects, but can access `URL`s coming from the same code base/document base.
- Use `getDocumentBase()`/`getCodeBase()` with an relative path to the image, and the applet will be portable (assuming the image is also uploaded to the same place).